# Is it safe to enable Remote Registry service in LAN (windows 7)

Tags: windows

I'd love to enable Remote Registry Service on most Windows computers in the office (LAN, behind a firewall), so that I can query their computer registry without paying them a desk visit, and ask them to pause their work for me to take a look.

But is it a good practice to set this service to run automatically?

I have set powershell execution policy to RemoteSigned on all computers in my domain, so that I can use powershell straight away on their machine. I'd love to be able to use powershell remoting, but I refrained from enabling remoting on all windows machines due to security concerns.. Am I being too cautious?

Thx in advance for any discussion. I'd love to see what is in action in other places..

Answer (score 6):

The Remote Registry service on all versions of Windows (that I'm aware of) is set to Automatic startup out of the box. Unless it's been reconfigured via GPO you shouldn't have to set it to Automatic startup, it should already be set that way.

Is it secure? Is it good practice? That depends entirely on the organization. I've seen organizations that left it at the default state of Automatic startup and I've seen organizations that have disabled it.

Comment: more precisely, it would depend on the security concept which is to be implemented in the organization or the specific network zone you are working in. Remote registry access relies upon RPC, which is a complex protocol in itself, where the implementation indeed has seen remote code execution vulnerabilities over the years, so for highly security-sensitive environments, it likely would be disallowed entirely. Powershell remoting uses WinRM, which is conceptually related to RPC but has a totally independent implementation.

Comment: In many deploy environments, a template is used that has Remote Registry disabled by default. It cannot be assumed that it is running.

Answer (score 1):

This service uses the same ports the rest of Windows networking does (445 and 139, although I'm not sure that 139 is even required for remote reg), so if you're already allowing file sharing and other Windows services on your network and consider it secure, then you're already allowing the appropriate ports.

Remote security is the same as local security for Registry access, for the HKLM hive that generally means being a local Administrator, although there are some specific rights that can be set that alter this behavior.

Since the better network security "scanners" such as Nessus rely on the ability to do remote registry access to evaluate a machine's security, I generally have it turned on in environments that I am A) confident of the network security on and B) have a documented need for the service. If it's a one time thing that you're asking about, you can always have whatever script you're using start the service and then stop it when it's done using WMI.

Comment: I'm evaluating at the moment whether there is a need to enable the remote registry service and was wondering whether you would mind either sharing why the service would be needed and what you consider a secure network?